# Install PHP 4 in Wamp, UwAmp or Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm .Net developer, and I found in company a physical RedHat server with a lot applications in PHP and I need to create a local server to start translate this PHP apps to .NET, but I need install PHP 4.4.5 server local to translate for .Net

I try Wamp but I can't install PHP 4.4.5

If UwAmp Show this error when I start apache **httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 166 of C:/UwAmp/bin/apache/conf/httpd.conf: LoadModule takes two arguments, a module name and the name of a shared object file to load it from 
Line 166**:

Line 166: **LoadModule PHP.4.4.5**

How I install PHP 4.4.5 version now a days?

Comment: "I need install PHP 4.4.5 server local to translate for .Net" makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to do? Run PHP on .NET should go to routes like https://www.peachpie.io/ To translate to other languages such as C#, I don't believe there are automatic tools.

Comment: I need to create dev's enviroment in PHP 4.4.5